# How these python for loop and slicing working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

1. How this statement will work?

   ```
   j for i in range(5)
   ```

   Example:

   ```
   x1=(j for i in range(5))
   ```

   will yield five 4's when iterated. Why it will not yield 01234 like when we replace j with i.
2. How this statement working?

   ```
   a = [0, 1, 2, 3]
   for a[-1] in a:
       print(a[-1])
   0
   1
   2
   2
   ```

Comment: `j for i in range(5)` will cause an exception since j is not defined, and all your for loop is doing is changing the last value `a` to the current value being iterated by the for loop and then printing that value.

Comment: If you are getting four 4's from the first example that just means `j` was previously defined in your code and it's value happened to be 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first example is a generator expression (the parentheses are required, so the first version you show doesn't actually make sense). The generator expression repeatedly yields `j`, which is not defined in the code you show. But from your description, it already has the value `4` in the environment you were testing in, so you see that value repeatedly. You never use the `i` value, which is what's getting the values from the `range`.

As for your other loop, `for a[-1] in a` keeps rebinding the last value in the list, and then printing it.

A for loop does an assignment to the target you give it between `for` and `in`. Usually you use a local variable name (like `i` or `j`), but you *can* use a more complicated assignment target, like `self.index` or, as in this case, `a[-1]`. It's very strange to be rewriting a value of your list as you iterate over it, but it's not forbidden.

You never get `3` printed out, because each of the previous assignments as you iterated overwrote it in the list. The last iteration doesn't change the value that gets printed, since you're assigning `a[-1]` to itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your first question raises error when iterating, as `j` is not defined. If you are getting any response from that, you probably have defined a value for `j` above your generator, which sounds to be `4` in your code.

About your second question:

when you have something like this:

```py
for i in a:
    ...
```

Actually you are are doing this in each cycle: `i=a[0], i=a[1], ...`.

When you write `a[-1] in a`, it is kind of equal to: `a[-1]=a[0], a[-1]=a[1], ...` and you are changing last element of `a` each time. So at the end, the last element of your list would be `2`.

Comment: Yes that's correct. I can see I have used j previously and now it makes sense. Thanks